# Interpret outputs of neural network

Tags: neural-network

I've implemented a neural network for prediction,
for the input data, I've used the following formula to normalize data
`Data_normalized_i= [Data_i - Min_data]/[Max_Data- Min_data]`

I've some questions:

1. How to interpret output of my network according to my inputs?
2. must I use the real data input to compare it with my outputs?
3. if I have to do some transformation of my outputs, so How? and for the test error in this case, will be it calculated from the output or from the transformed outputs?

regards.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please [read the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to learn about what kinds of questions can and should be posed here.

Answer (score 1):

1) In a standard three layer MLP, the output node (or nodes), will have be threshold functions that will either tend towards 0 or 1 after training for classification, or a real valued number within a certain range for regression/function approximation.

2)  You can and should use normalized data as you are doing, generally speaking.

3)  For classification, treat the outputs as boolean values.  For regression/approximation, then the output corresponds to the best estimate of the network based on the training data.